# SwipeRefresh not working add RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, touch, swiperefreshlayout

I have a case when I need to have some logic in RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener.

Also I need functionality of SwipeRefreshLayout.

But when I set LinearLayoutManager to my RecyclerView and add OnItemTouchListener to it - SwipeRefresh doesn't work.

This is code of my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            // some custom logic here
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(rv, e);
        }
    });
}
}
```

And this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor_list);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_doctorsList);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);

        getDoctorList();


        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        getDoctorList();
                    }
                }
        );

 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new 
 RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Intent i=new Intent(EventActivity.this,ClubActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(CLUB_ID,list.get(position).getId());
        startActivity(i);
    }
}));

 }
```

for stop swipeReferesh:

```
 swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false); // stopping swipe refresh
```

Comment: But in this solution there is no RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener on RecyclerView. I don't need RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener. I need exactly TouchListener with onInterceptTouchEvent() method

Comment: why are you using addOnItemTouchListener @Pablo

Comment: In my case I need to disable vertical scroll by user touches. But should be enabled programm scroll. And in onInterceptTouchEvent() method I can disable scroll of RecyclerView on ACTION_MOVE

Comment: You can't use both the things on same . when you disable scrolling , swiperefresh automatically stops working.

Comment: but it's strange. Cause I really need this behaviour. And I think that Android can be customized like this